# Google play store: set language to the local language

Tags: google-play-store

I am in Germany, I want to set up Play Store to display and search/install apps in German language.

My phone's default language is French. I do not want another language.

I did set up my Google account language to German as the main and only language

Still Play store will display all in French. I cannot find how to switch languages.

What to do to get it into German?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set your System display language to German, not your Google account language to German:

- Paramètres -> Paramètres Avancés -> Langues & Saisie -> Langue -> Allemand (Deutsch)
- Einstellungen -> Erweiterte Einstellungen -> Sparche & Eingabe -> Sparche -> Deutsch

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but is it possible to switch the language without changing phone main language?